# Laravel like where, orWhere

Tags: php, laravel, search

Делаю поиск по базе, хочу, чтоб дал результат по первым параметрам, то есть, сначала дать все совпадения с title, потом после этого - совпадения с full. Пробовал через where and orWhere, не получилось.

```
$ads = $ads->where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->input('q') . '%')->where('status','active')->orWhere('full', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->input('q') . '%')->where('status','active');
```

Comment: `$ads->where([['title', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->input('q') . '%'], ['full', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->input('q') . '%'], ['status', '=', 'active']])->get();`

Comment: Спасибо за отклик, но таким образом тоже не получился, не дает то что нужен(((

Comment: Я думаю в таком случае лучше будет сделать два отдельных запроса.

Comment: Вам надо выбрать где title like q а потом среди этой выборки ещё раз искать по full?

Comment: Ага, просто сначала нужен показать результат title а потом full

Answer (score 1):

```php
<?php

$term = '%' . $request->input('q') . '%';
$ads = $ads
    ->where(function ($query) use ($term) {
        $query
            ->where('title', 'LIKE', $term)
            ->orWhere('full', 'LIKE', $term)
        ;
    })
    ->where('status','active')
;
```